# Verificação de URL independentemente do servidor

Tags: javascript, url

Preciso verificar a `URL` de uma página em JavaScript. Estou exibindo o seguinte  alert:

```
alert(window.location.href.toString())
```

A seguinte `ULR` é exibida no alert :

```
http://localhost:9577/Painel/Index
```

Não posso comparar a string inteira retornada pois nem sempre o servidor vai ser `localhost:9577`. Como faço para verificar apenas o diretorio `/Painel/Index` independentemente do servidor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O objeto `window.location` tem algumas propriedades que vão te ajudar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
No seu caso, `window.location.pathname` vai retornar a informação que você precisa.
A exceção vai ser para páginas que implementam URLs como "meusite.com.br/site".

Comment: pathname. Isso mesmo que eu estava procurando. Obgrigado